# Firebase remove observers with variable handles?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I am adding an observer for every post in a feed, as such: `let postChangingDetailsObservation = Database.database().reference().child("postDetails").child(postID).child(UID!)` For every postID, an observer is added. Is there a way to remove all these observers when the view disappears, as, say `Database.database.reference.child("postDetails").removeAllObservers()`? How else would I be able to remove every single observer added when the view disappears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `removeAllObservers` removes all observers from that specific reference. It does **not** remove observers from child nodes.

If you want to remove all observers you attached, you will either have to track all observers, or at the very least all nodes that you attached observers to.

Comment: Hmmm so I keep an array of handles and add each handle to the array? Also, since there are so many observers (maybe a 100, etc.) is it worth it to remove them all every time the view disappears as firebase documentation recommends?

Comment: or would it be better to iterate over every post in the post array and remove all the observers directly from their reference ie `for post in PostList... reference.child("postDetails").child(postID).child(userID).removeAllObservers()`?

Comment: You also need the reference/query, so can't just keep the handles. But if you know the post IDs, that could also work. There is not really a single best practice here.

Comment: So would it be a strain to remove all the observers on view did disappear?

Comment: Also, is it necessary to remove firestore observers, too? One final question, if there is no path that exists as specified will the app crash? For instance, if I remove an observer at a path that doesn't exist, will I receive an error?

Comment: The same applies to both databases. I'm not sure what to comment on it being a strain: if you need to remove the listeners, you need to know what nodes to remove them from.

Comment: makes sense. I was wondering whether it would be feasible to remove one hundred observers at a time but it looks okay now.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, just one more thing - if I have an observer that's a query, as such `let messageRef = Database.database().reference().child("conversations").queryOrdered(byChild: "reciever").queryEqual(toValue: userHash)` Can I just remove messageRef observers to get rid of all the observers for the query?

Comment: Yeah, if you call "remove all observers" it will remove all observers on that query.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, appreciate your time.

Comment: I tried removing all the observers on view did disappear and adding all the observers on view did appear as https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/best-practices-for-ios-uiviewcontroller_6.html that documentation suggested. However, the problem is now that the data is duplicated because it keeps adding conversations to an array already filled from the previous observer. Should I clear my array each time? That seems pretty data intensive...Essentially, all these removing observers is just so I properly logout a user...

Comment: We're not going to a specific use-case, which I think is straying a bit far from the original question. But you'll either need to clear the existing contents, or need to ensure you only get data that isn't shown yet.

Comment: Sounds good! I figured out the solution to logging out - essentially, I made all the queries static variables, so I could call them from other view controllers. Then, when the log out button is pressed, I clear all the arrays and remove the observers from every single static variable. I add an observer to wait for the user's authentication to change, and then I present the other view controller. Thanks!